# ccnet email permalink to build

Tags: email, permalinks, ccnet-config

Is there a way to make ccnet's email publisher (or another publisher that sends emails) include a permalink to the actual build that it refers to?

I actually want to be able to link to the unit test results report, so I also need to be able to customise it a bit too, but a link to the build report of the actual build would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would include the link to the build report but you can include the build report (or parts of it, e.g. unit test results) directly in the email. Just like in the dashboard you can format the output using xsl transformations specified in ccservice.exe.config.

Comment: I looked at this, but in order to create the link I need to know the name of the log file. Which you don't have access to during an XSL transform; and you can't build since it depends on things like the build success (which just gets nasty).